# Byobu, empty windows names

Tags: byobu

I have been enjoying byobu very much. It is a great improvement compare to the bare screen application. Since its installation on my Ubuntu 14.04, I have never seen windows named correctly. They always have this format: 
`0:-`,    `1:-`, `2:-#`, or `3:-*` (current window)

How to I get it to show something like this?:

```
0:bash    1:Rscript    2:tasks   3:latex*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update ubuntu to the latest version of byobu on 14.04 solved this problem.

Comment: You can also rename each pane [with F8 keybinding](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/byobu.1.html#keybindings)